# Unable to clear Joomla 3 cache

Tags: caching, joomla3.0

I am currently working on a website in Joomla 3. In one module I edited a php-file of which I could see the updated result.

Later on i wanted to continue updating this file and edited and uploaded it into the ftp. The upload was successful and I can go to the files Web-path and see that it is uploaded. However the website only shows the version I first uploaded.

I have turned off cache, the cache plugin, the gzip page compression, edited the .htaccess, turned off the template caching, manually removed the cache files in joomla. I have spoken to my webhosts company and they have cleared any cache they might have had. No change. Joomla still creates the cache files, the one I notice is the one mentioned above.

Is there any more cache option I'm missing, or maybe something I can do to remove this cache file?

Answer (score 0):

Found it myself actually (with some outside help) thought i would share it here: It was not actually the cache but under the template folder and then the html folder some modules saves file copies which overrides the ones under the module-folder